# recurrence relation and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

let $a_0$ and $a_1$ be arbitrary real number.
for $n\geq2$
$$n(n-1)a_n=(n-1)(n-2)a_{n-1}-(n-3)a_{n-2}$$
find $a_0+a_1+...$

my book says that the answer is $a_1+a_0(e-1)$ where $e$ is $2.71828$ thing. I don't know how this appeared.

Comment: This probably uses math you haven't learned yet, given that you think of $e$ as "that 2.71828 thing."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fully agree with @saulspatz's comment. The problem is not simple and I then suppose that they almost ask you to use brute force.

Let
$$a_n=\frac {(n-1)(n-2)a_{n-1}-(n-3)a_{n-2} }{n(n-1)}\qquad\text{with}\qquad a_0=\alpha\qquad a_1=\beta$$

This makes the first terms of the sequence to be
$$\left\{\alpha ,\beta ,\frac{\alpha }{2},\frac{\alpha }{6},\frac{\alpha
   }{24},\frac{\alpha }{120},\frac{\alpha }{720},\frac{\alpha }{5040},\frac{\alpha
   }{40320},\frac{\alpha }{362880},\frac{\alpha }{3628800}\right\}$$ where you can recognize the factorials in denominators. Rewriting the sequence, it is 
$$\left\{\frac{\alpha }{1!} ,\beta ,\frac{\alpha }{2!},\frac{\alpha }{3!},\frac{\alpha
   }{4!},\frac{\alpha }{5!},\frac{\alpha }{6!},\frac{\alpha }{7!},\frac{\alpha
   }{8!},\frac{\alpha }{9!},\frac{\alpha }{10!}\right\}$$ Then
$$\sum_{n=0}^p a_n=\beta+\alpha\sum_{n=0}^p \frac 1{n!}$$
Now, "remember" that the infinite expansion of the exponential function is
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n!}\implies e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {1}{n!}$$

Do you see the link ?